# Converting a complete Angular application into a WebComponent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-component

I have a full Angular 16 application, containing routing, multiple components and services and I need to convert it into a single Webcomponent, that can be loaded via the `script` tag in an external UI application/shell.

So far, all the tutorials and resources I have come across demonstrate transforming just a single component Angular app into a Webcomponent using Angular Elements, such as this example -

```
import { Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import  { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing. Module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home. Component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, HomeComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    const el = createCustomElement(HomeComponent, {injector: this. Injector});
    customElements.define('element-home', el);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {}
 }
```

Here, I have a single component in the Angular app, called `HomeComponent`, from which I can create a Webcomponent titled `<element-home>`. This can be loaded, as an example, into an HTML page this way -

```
<body>
  <element-home></element-home>
  <script src="...." /> // bundled Angular javascript files
</body>
```

But, how do I transform a complete Angular app (with routing) into a Webcomponent? My angular component structure looks like this -

```
- AppComponent
  <router-outlet> 
  |
   - HomeComponent // for /home route
   - DetailComponent // for /detail route
   - DetailService
```

Additionally, any tutorials/resources/guides on this topic would be appreciated!

Comment: It is quite easy. But the question is: what version of Angular do you use?

Comment: @NgDaddy I use Angular 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you use Angular 16 you can utilize standalone API (see the stackblitz link at the bottom):

(**WARNING**: *the app should not contain any lazy loaded parts*)

When you build that app in the repo you will get three js files:

1. runtime.js
2. polyfills.js
3. main.js

You have to concat them into one file keeping the order above.
This way you will get one js file with your new webcomponent.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter, Router, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { createApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'home-component',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h2 class="my-class">Hello from {{ name }}!</h2>
  `,
  styles: `
    .my-class {
      color: green;
    }
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
})
export class HomeComponent {
  name = 'HomeComponent';
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1 class="my-class">Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  styles: `
    .my-class {
      color: red;
    }
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'AppComponent';

  private router = inject(Router);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.initialNavigation();
  }
}

async function webComponentApp() {
  const app = await createApplication({
    providers: [
      provideRouter([
        { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      ]),
    ],
  });
  const element = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {
    injector: app.injector,
  });
  customElements.define('my-app-webcomponent', element);
}

(async function () {
  await webComponentApp();
})();
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qrjdcs?file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Thank You for the example, but I'm having a hard time replicating your example for my project which uses `@NgModules`, not standalone components. It looks like your main bootstrapping code is in the `webComponentApp()` function, which lives in `main.ts` which also contains all other components. How would this translate to the older style? Where should I place the `webComponentApp()` function? If I put it in `app.component.ts`, it throws an error - `core.mjs:28282 Uncaught Error: NG0400: A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first.`

Comment: It looks like this is because `main.ts` already seems to be bootstrapping the Angular app through `AppModule` - `// platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
//   .catch(err => console. Error(err));`... not sure how to adjust this based on your changes

Comment: I migrated my app to using standalone components only (no NgModules), and now it works on port 4200 (similar to your stackblitz example), but if you try to replicate it in a new `index.html` file and add the bundled 3 generated JS files, it doesn't show anything. Maybe you can give this a shot too..

Comment: Have you added the newly created webcomponent tag to the new `index.html` file?

Comment: Yes, of course, I have the new webcomponent tag in `index.html` followed by the script tag to inject the single JS file obtained by concating the three angular generated JS files. Things work fine if there is a single Angular component in the webcomponent, but if there are multiple components with routing, something is breaking. You can perhaps check by using your `<my-app-webcomponent></my-app-webcomponent>`  tag in a separate index.html file, similarly.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your setup. It works fine with any complex and huge Angular application encapsulated into a webcomponent even with the routing. My experience on production :) Remember not to have anything lazy loaded in the app. I've enhanced the stackblitz a bit https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qrjdcs.  btw can you see any error in the console?

Comment: Yes, the one major difference I can see in my setup is - I have the older Angular project structuring where each component is located in its own file. So in my `main.ts`, there is a `bootstrapApplication()` function which calls `AppComponent`, and in `app.component.ts`, I have your `webComponentApp()` function. Whereas in your case, everything is in `main.ts` directly. Code - https://pastebin.com/nAeGkkaC And yes, there is one error in the console:  `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002` - which seems to be about Routing, but it doesn't show any error in the dev server on port 4200...

Comment: Essentially, the `bootstrapApplication()` function in `main.ts` seems to be clashing with the `createApplication()` function in `app.component.ts`.. I guess I should be keeping only one, but i'm not sure how to reach `AppComponent` from `main.ts` if I delete the `bootstrapApplication()` function.

Comment: Structuring does not matter. In the stackblitz example I keep all in one file just for a simplification sake. Just to make it easier for you to get it I've splitted it into files https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qrjdcs. See how main.ts looks now and try to do the same. Do not run `bootstrapApplication`, run just `createApplication` as it is in the main.ts. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256916/discussion-between-ngdaddy-and-dust-in-the-wind).

Comment: Thank you very much, esp. for the updated/split code. I was able to figure out why it wasn't working for me (just a blank screen) - so in my `app.component.html`, I only had `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`.  But it also needed a `routerLink` to navigate to the home page route or  the default route - `/`, like so - `<a [routerLink]="['/']" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>`.  Alternatively, using `router. Navigate()` in the `ngOnInit()` of `app.component.ts` also works. Any idea why this is needed? It works without it in localhost:4200... I guess we can continue discussion in chat too.

Comment: You are welcome :) In the example you can see that `this.router.initialNavigation();` is called on `ngOnInit()` of the app component - this initializes the routing the same way as Anular does for regular SPA app. Use `this.router.initialNavigation();` instead of any other workarounds :)

Answer (score 1):

Complementary the NgDaddy answer, some advertisements:

I think remember read in some where that the "scripts" should be inserted at the end of the "body" -after the tag of your app-.

```
  <body>
    <my-app>
      loadding...
    </my-app>

    <script src="...."></script>
    <script src="...."></script>
    <script src="...."></script>
  </body>
```

To use with modules you should write

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector:Injector) {}
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    customElements.define(
      'my-app',
      createCustomElement(AppComponent, {injector: this.injector})
    )
  }
 }
```

You can use "concat" to join the three bundles.For this.

1. Add the concat

   ```
   npm i concat
   ```
2. Create a file concat.js in the way

   ```
   var concat = require('concat');
   concat(['./dist/runtime.js',
           './dist/polyfills.js',
           './dist/main.js'],'./dist/my-app.js');
   ```
3. And in package.json, **before the build** write

   ```
   //add this line
   "build-element": "ng build --prod=true --localize --output-hashing=none &&
                      node ./concat.js",

   //before
   "build":.....
   ```

When you use routing, it's possible you need use [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy)

```
{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
```